# Calculated Sum using Recursion LISP

Tags: lisp

I am a beginner to LISP. I encountered the following error ** - IF: variable SUM-REC has no value but have no clue on how to resolve it. Here is my code.

```
  (defun sum-rec (n) 
  (if (not (eq n 0))

    (+ (sum-rec(-n 1) )n )
    0
    )

(format t "ans = ~a~%" (sum-rec 4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `eq` to compare numbers, because `eq` compares *objects* and there is no guarantee that this will work for numbers as expected. Use `eql`, `=`, or in this case `/=` instead.

Functions calls are expressed as `(func p1 p2 ...)`, not `func(p1 p2 ...)`.

So the correct code is

```
(defun sum-rec (n) 
  (if (/= n 0)
      (+ (sum-rec (- n 1)) n)
      0))
```

testing:

```
CL-USER> (format t "ans = ~a~%" (sum-rec 4))
ans = 10
NIL

CL-USER> (+ 1 2 3 4)
10
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks. Can i ask why?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question... why *what*?

Answer (score -1):

1. Check the parenthesis: they are unbalanced.
2. Please, format code properly: it helps to read it and find the error.
3. In Lisp whitespace is important: it separates the items. In `(sum-rec (-n 1))` there is a space missing between `-` and `n`. Lisp will read it as a function `-n` applied to `1`, which is obviously not what was meant to be there.

After fixing these everything works:

```
(defun sum-rec (n) 
  (if (not (eq n 0))
    (+ (sum-rec(- n 1)) n)
    0))

> (format t "ans = ~A~%" (sum-rec 4))
ans = 10
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Gosh, LISP is a pain when it comes to parenthesis

Comment: @Hero1134 It helps to use editors that highlight matching parentheses. Or even won't let you put unbalanced parenthesis. I know Emacs + SLIME (+ Paredit or Smartparens) is a (rather steep) learning curve, but their use pays off.